# Characters to phone numbers converter java

Tags: java, converters, phone-number

How do i modify the program to allow the user to enter more than 1 word and have a hypen after every 4 digits in the output? Do i create another loop at the end of the while loop ? what should i do?

```
import java.util.Arraylist;
import java.util.list;
import java.util.Scanner;
{     public static void main (String[] args)     
     {     
       Scanner  console = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = console.nextLine();
        while(!line.equals("")) {
        input.add(line);
        line = console.nextLine();
 }
        for(String Letter: input)
        {       
            System.out.println("Enter the a word to be converted : ");
            String Letter = console.nextLine();
            Letter = Letter.replaceAll("\\s", "");
            Letter = Letter.toLowerCase();
            String  Number="";
            int count=0;
            int  i=0;

 while(count < Letter.length())       
{

  switch(Letter.charAt(i))        {
           case 'A':case 'B':case 'C': case 'a': case 'b': case 'c':                  

                    Number += "2";
                    count++;
                    break;
                    case 'D':case 'E':case 'F': case 'd': case 'e': case 'f':                Number += "3";
                    count++;
                    break;
                    case 'G':case 'H':case 'I': case 'g': case 'h': case 'i':               Number += "4";
                    count++;
                    break;
                    case 'J':case 'K':case 'L': case 'j': case 'k': case 'l':               Number += "5";
                    count++;
                    break;
                    case 'M':case 'N':case 'O': case 'm': case 'n': case 'o':           Number += "6";
                    count++;
                    break;
                    case 'P':case 'R':case 'S': case 'p': case 'r': case 's':               Number += "7";
                    count++;
                    break;
                    case 'T':case 'U':case 'V': case 't': case 'u': case 'v':              Number += "8";
                    count++;
                    break;
                    case 'W':case 'X':case 'Y':case 'Z': case 'w': case 'x': case 'y': case 'z':          Number += "9";
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
                if(  count==3) {        Number += "-";
                }
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println( Number );
        }
    }
}
```

Output now

```
 Enter the word to be converted :
 callhome
 225-54663
```

Expected output

```
 Enter the words to be converted :
 callhome
 hereherehereherehere
 comecomecomecomecome

 225-5466-3
 437-3437-3437-3437-3437-3
 266-3266-3266-3266-3266-3
```

Comment: please show the output you are getting and desire output

Comment: @PiyushMittal i have updated the expected output. how do i modify the current code to process as many telephone numbers to be converted in 1 time

Comment: 225-54663 same you are getting is it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `console.nextLine()` in a loop to get all the words into a array list. And then you can loop over the array list to perform the logic. Multiple comments on the code:

1. You are converting the word to uppercase and then lowercase. Your switch need not look for both upper and lower cases.
2. You are checking for count==3 for adding a '-'. Similarly you can use `(count-3)%4 == 0` to see whether at 4th character boundary.
3. Don't you need to check for '1' also?

This is how you can get your input into an array list.

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
String line = console.nextLine();
while(!line.equals("")) {
    input.add(line);
    line = console.nextLine();
}
```

Once this is done, you can loop over the array as follows:

```
for(String Letter: input) {
  // Whole of your code goes here.
}
```

Look out for syntax errors. I am just typing in the browser directly.

Comment: Thanks for you input. And no i do not need to check for 1, the number 1 doesnt have any characters assigned to it.      console.nextLine() do i add it after the while statement? But how do i allow it to run after input the different words?

Comment: Looking at the desired output, I think you should read your input first. Creating a new array list for holding the numbers. And loop till `console.nextLine` returns an empty string while adding into the list. Then loop on the list elements with your current logic setting `Letter` to the element.

Comment: I'm sorry but how do i go about doing that? Just a beginner and haven't look up on the creating an array list yet.

Comment: Is creating an arraylist the only way to achieve that output? Still couldn't really understand the method you have given.

Isn't the String line = console.nextLine() already define on my code already?

Comment: In your Expected output, the converted numbers are printed after all the input is given. If that is the case, you need to capture the input first.

Comment: I have added in the code you have provided. Is that how i do it?

Answer (score 0):

please update the code as below:

```
if(  count==3) 
 Number += "-";

if(count>4 && ((count+1)%4)==0)
 Number += "-";
```

Comment: It does not work. Still only added the first hyphen but not the subsequence 1s

Comment: sorry i could not check the output:// could you please post the output here you are getting from this code

Comment: that's alright i have make it worked @KDM 's solution does it. Thanks a bunch anyway!